# Controlling order of XPages CSS using mobile theme

Tags: css, mobile, xpages

When using the XPages Mobile theme the CSS files I add to the page as resources are added before the CSS files provided by IBM as part of the mobile theme.

Example:

```
<xp:this.resources>
  <xp:styleSheet href="css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"></xp:styleSheet>
  <xp:styleSheet href="/mobile.css"></xp:styleSheet>
</xp:this.resources>
```

Generate the following HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/redpill/graph.nsf/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/redpill/graph.nsf/mobile.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.8.1/dojox/mobile/themes/iphone/iphone.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/xsp/.ibmxspres/.extlib/css/customMobile.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/xsp/.ibmxspres/.extlib/css/customIphone.css">
```

Is there a way to force my own custom controls to be added after IBM's? It is more challenging (but not impossible) to control the style when my own CSS is listed first in the chain.

Comment: Can you show how you're including them on your XPage? I assume they're being included as resources under <xp:view>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I am not sure it complies with the W3 spec but I can simply add the link in the Body by placing it as XML code inside the XPage.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/redpill/graph.nsf/mobile.css"></link>
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that using the mobile tools doesn't change the way objects are loaded.

I use a theme, and my CSS files appear after the generated CSS files.

```
<theme extends="webstandard">
    <resource>
        <content-type>text/css</content-type>
        <href>crmStyle.css</href>
    </resource>
</theme>
```

Generates the following on pages using the theme:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.8.1/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.8.1/ibm/domino/widget/layout/css/domino-default.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/domjava/xsp/theme/webstandard/xsp.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/domjava/xsp/theme/webstandard/xspLTR.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/domjava/xsp/theme/webstandard/xspSF.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Path/crmStyle.css">
```

To test CSS files with mobile theme, I did the following:

[image: Select Mobile Theme]

Created new page m_Landing. Added CSS File as Resource.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom" themeId="MyTheme">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:styleSheet href="/crmStyle.css"></xp:styleSheet>
    </xp:this.resources>
</xp:view>
```

Generated HTML:

```
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.8.1/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="locale: 'en-us'"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.8.1/ibm/xsp/widget/layout/layers/xspClientDojo.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Path/crmStyle.css">
</head>
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate that when a mobile theme has been applied. My experience has been that when a mobile theme is nominated it ignores the theme setting for the application.

Comment: Hmm. Actually, I just tested it with the mobile theme (Creating a new m_ XPage and i included the styleSheet as a resource, and it still appeared after the generated files. What version of Designer are you using?

Comment: Thats puzzling. In your example I don't actually see any of the mobile CSS files IBM provide to support the mobile devices. I would expect to see customMobile.css and two other CSS for either Android or IPhone. Its getting my custom CSS to appear after those that is the challenge. Removing them completely is not an option.  I am running 9.0 for both Designer and Domino.

Comment: Perhaps we're defining our mobile themes differently. Are you following the same workflow I am? (Editing XSP Properties, creating XPage with prefix)?

Comment: Based upon the HTML you have generated I am guessing that the XPage doesn't have any actual mobile controls. The IBM CSS files are only added when one or more mobile controls are defined on the XPage (regardless of the mobile prefix setting). My testing is showing if I build the application after setting the enabling of the mobile prefix then the existing theme resources are excluded.