# How to override mobile css in Xpages Mobile App

Tags: iphone, css, xpages

I am writing an iPhone app that has some Xpages included in the app. In Xpages I am using the Single Application Page and then Application Pages. They work fairly slick.

However, in my first page I am getting a 44px space that I do not want. I noticed that there is CSS that causes this:

```
.mblView {
padding top: 44px !important;
}
```

I have a picture of how it looks here:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/28998410@N06/

How can I override that css so that I don't get that horrible looking bar at the top.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Bryan

Comment: Could use an example of the XPages markup for the controls on that page. That might provide an idea of how to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

The 44px padding is there because the design expects a heading before the content. The heading needs 44px space. Here's a simple example where the heading is included:

```
<xe:appPage id="appPage1" pageName="homePage" resetContent="false">
    <xe:djxmHeading id="homePageHeading" label="Heading"></xe:djxmHeading>
    <xe:djxmRoundRectList id="djxmRoundRectList1">
        Content
    </xe:djxmRoundRectList>
</xe:appPage>
```

You can create your own custom css with the following content and add it as a stylesheet resource to your XPage. This should override the standard CSS:

```
.mblView {
    padding-top: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: We've recently ran into an issue where this isn't working because with use of the mobile theme (assumption) it loads all of our resources first and then loads the mobile css thus negating our overrides. Since IBM's style rule is also marked as !important it overrides our !important. See this SO question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959874/controlling-order-of-xpages-css-using-mobile-theme

Comment: Have you tried som dojo.addOnLoad() magic that adds the necessary CSS inline on the element? That might work

Comment: Think we just added the link tag inside the < body > to get around it